# rake task to synchronise with Amazon AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a project I am working on my local computer, and deployed in Heroku Server, with Amazon S3 as its assets repository.

I store everything inside public folder into Amazon server, and this folder is git ignored when pushing to heroku server.

Problem happens when I have another programmer working on this project. She can upload her assets to Amazon server, and they show correctly online, but I cannot pull her changes.

So my question is simple, is there already a rake task to synchronise my public folder with amazon s3 repository?

**Note**
I am using [s3sync](http://www.s3sync.net/wiki) application but seems like it only goes one way i.e. I can send whatever in my public folder, but it doesn't get the files in repository.

Comment: anyone please? Or maybe can anyone point me out a good workflow when working on heroku with amazon aws in a team project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking into the same thing, but without Heroku.  I think the best thing to do is to check your public assets into version control, and then push those out to s3 when you deploy.

I came across a nice rake script to do this, perhaps it will work for you too:

http://ariejan.net/2011/01/01/rake-task-to-sync-your-assets-to-amazon-s3cloudfront/